# How to import from python scripts located in different subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a university project, I have a bunch of `python` files that all have separate use cases with no central code entry point. Since I sorted the code into meaningful subdirectories, the imports from within those subdirectories are broken. When calling a script from one of the subdirectories, the result is:

```
  File "project/glm/predict_for_all.py", line 9, in <module>
    from util.misc import load_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

The same happens if I change the imports to `from project.util.misc import load_data`: no module named `project`.

Calling e.g. `visualise_all.py` works, using `from util.misc ...` import statements.

For reference, here is a (slightly simplified) directory tree.

```
project/
├── project
|   ├── ann
|   │   ├── __init__.py
|   │   ├── predict_for_all.py
|   |   └── predict_for_one.py 
|   ├── glm
|   │   ├── __init__.py
|   │   ├── predict_for_all.py
|   |   └── predict_for_one.py 
|   ├── util
|   │   ├── __init__.py
|   │   ├── linear_modelling.py
|   │   ├── misc.py
|   │   └── plotting.py
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── visualise_one.py
|   └── visualise_all.py
└── test
```

Things I have tried so far:

- added `__init__.py` files to every directory
- changed imports to include `project` (before: `from util.misc import ..`, now: `from project.util.misc import ..`)
- tried relative imports (`from ..util.misc ...`): error changes to `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Things the SO chat has suggested:

- add a `setup.py` and install the project in `editable` mode to help resolve import conflicts. Admittedly I have no researched this a lot, I mainly assumed from some searching that I would need a central entry point in my code to use this approach properly

Things I have not tried:

- adding all project (sub)directories to `PATH`/`PYTHONPATH`. Gauging from other answers on SO, this looks like a workaround. However, having to manually do this for every project sounds like it will lead to massive cluttering of environment variables and difficult-to-track work overhead (please correct me if this in fact common practice)

Things I have noticed:

- my IDE (vscode) can autocomplete the path when imports start with the project name. I'm using `pylance` with options `autoSearchPaths: True` and `extraPaths: ['abs_path/to/project/project']`, suggesting that my python installation (outside of the editor) cannot see beyond the top-level folder of the project
- when opening a `python` console in the terminal at `project/` and typing out the imports like `import project` and `from project.util.misc import load_data`, they pass without any NotFoundError. What this implies, I cannot say...

Suggestions to solve this or diagnose the issue deeper are very welcome! Ideally, I would also like to know how to entirely avoid problems like this with future work...

Comment: "I mainly assumed from some searching that I would need a central entry point in my code to use this approach properly" You don't. Installation prepares a project for *import*; an entry point is needed for *execution* of a project. Note that a package may have several entry points, if you need them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So after installing the project in editable mode, you call it the same as before (`python project/glm/prepare_for_all.py`) instead of `project --some_parameter to_indicate_what_to_execute` and the imports should resolve?

Comment: Ideally, you call it as ``python -m project.glm.prepare_for_all`` or even via an installed console_script as ``prepare_for_all``, but just ``python project/glm/prepare_for_all.py`` should work as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi After installing the package, calling it with and without `-m` works for the scripts in subdirectories, thank you. Could you elaborate on "installed via console_script" please?

Comment: Packages allow to define [callables that serve as executable entry points](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html). Installing the package then automatically creates scripts, with each script calling one of these entry points.